# changing the color of each header which is dynamically adding to a span using one id

Tags: javascript, php, html

There exist some institute data in mysql database.whenever i click on view icon,it shows me the details of institute in a modal.and the institute name i am getting dynamically through one id.i want to change the color of each institute name

here is my view part`

```
<div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #fff;border-bottom-color: #e5e5e5;">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="viewinstname" name="viewinstname" style="font-size: 18px;line-height: 1.42857;margin: 0;"><img src ="" id="inst_logo" name="inst_logo" title="Institute Logo" style="height: 30px;width: 44px;"><span id="institutename" style="color: green;"> </span></h4>
</div>
```

here is my js part`

```
function viewInstitute(event) {
    $('#viewInstituteModal').modal('show'); //Institute details modal 
    $('#view_type').val('view_Institute');
    var oTable = $('#Institute_table').dataTable();
    var oTable1 = $('#Institute_table').dataTable();
    var row;
    if (event.target.tagName == "BUTTON")
        row = event.target.parentNode.parentNode;
    else if (event.target.tagName == "I")
        row = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    $('#institutename').html(oTable.fnGetData(row)['inst_name']);
}
```

[image: institute 1 details]

[image: institute 2 details]

Comment: Is the question that you want to randomly apply a color to each institutes modal header?

Comment: yes.every institute header must not be same color.

Comment: Random except white I guess

Comment: yes @kerbholz  except white

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method on `$('#institutename')` to change its color attribute. e.g.

`color` can be set to the most frequent color in the logo or some other factor. Here is a case using a color than contrasts with the most frequent color.

You can optimize this routine by moving the work to find most frequent color in the logo to a service worker.

```js
function getMostProminentColor({
  canvas,
  ctx
}) {
  var colorFreq = {},
    sortedColors = [],
    data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data,
    mostProminent;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
    var key = [data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2], data[i + 3]].join('-');
    colorFreq[key] && colorFreq[key]++;
    if (colorFreq[key]) {
      colorFreq[key]++;
    } else {
      colorFreq[key] = 1;
    }
  }
  sortedColors = Object.keys(colorFreq).sort(
    function(a, b) {
      return -(colorFreq[a] - colorFreq[b]);
    }
  );

  mostProminent = sortedColors[0];
  var colorWithAlpha = mostProminent.split('-'),
    contrastColor = colorWithAlpha.slice(0, 3).map((i) => 255 - +i),
    alpha = colorWithAlpha.slice(3, ).map((i) => 255 / +i),
    constrastColorWithAlpha = contrastColor.concat(alpha).join();
  return ['rgba(', constrastColorWithAlpha, ')'].join('');

}

function setColor($el) {
  return function(color) {
      return $el.css('color', color);
  }
}

function setText($el, text) {
  return function() {
     $('#institutename').html(text);
  }
}

function loadImage(src) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image,
    promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      img.onload = function() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        resolve({
          ctx,
          canvas
        });
      }
      img.onerror = function(err) {
        reject({
          err
        });
      }
    });

  img.src = src;
  return promise;
}



$(document).ready(function() {
  var $el = $('#institutename');
  var logoURI = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyBAMAAADsEZWCAAAAG1BMVEXMzMyWlpaqqqq3t7exsbGcnJy+vr6jo6PFxcUFpPI/AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAQUlEQVQ4jWNgGAWjgP6ASdncAEaiAhaGiACmFhCJLsMaIiDAEQEi0WXYEiMCOCJAJIY9KuYGTC0gknpuHwXDGwAA5fsIZw0iYWYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';

  loadImage(logoURI)
    .then(getMostProminentColor)
    .then(setColor($el))
    .then(setText($el, 'hello'))
    .catch(console.log);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="institutelogo" src="//placehold.it/50x50" /> <span id="institutename" style="color: red"></span>
```

**Note that** you can use color hex codes, RGB cubic coordinate system and HSL coordinate system aside from color keywords. e.g.:

```
$('#institutename').css('color', 'rgb(244,20,10)')
```

Also, `logoURI` doesn't necessarily need be a data URI. I used it here because I couldn't find an image with the right Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: if i use .css() method on $('#institutename') it changes all the institute name to only that particular color.i want to fix different color to all the institute.

Comment: Well, there is that. However, you can make color value a variable that is computed.

Comment: See @kerbholz comment about not setting the color to white